# Qt Installer project: how to generate package.xml and config.xml

Tags: qt-installer

I try to make my Qt Installer project more comfortable.

I need to centralize information about my application and components (config.xml and package.xml) in one file. I don't want to jump on different files with same name and search for changeable elements between xml tags.

My first thougt is doing it right in *.pro file of installer project. I place sections of variables in header of installer project file. But where I need to place the code for xml generating?

What is the better (native / comfortable / crossplatform) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple here: you cannot generate XML files for Qt Installer: you write them manually, as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-tutorial.html).

> This section describes the following tasks that you must accomplish to create the installer:
>
> 1. Create a *package directory* that will contain all the configuration files and installable packages.
> 2. Create a *configuration file* that contains information about how to build the installer binaries and online repositories.
> 3. Create a *package information file* that contains information about the installable components.
> 4. Create installer content and copy it to the package directory.
> 5. Use the **binarycreator** tool to create the *installer*.

However, if you look closer [at the examples](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qtifwexamples.html), you can still generate the installer in the *.pro file. Let's pick an example randomly, [System Info](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-systeminfo-systeminfo-pro.html):

```
TEMPLATE = aux

INSTALLER = installer

INPUT = $$PWD/config/config.xml $$PWD/packages
example.input = INPUT
example.output = $$INSTALLER
example.commands = ../../bin/binarycreator -c $$PWD/config/config.xml -p $$PWD/packages ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
example.CONFIG += target_predeps no_link combine

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += example

OTHER_FILES = README
```

If you want to apply this to your project, I think you'll have to modify the `../../bin/binarycreator` line and make it system aware, by changing your PATH. It might be possible to call an external script and parse XML files, and make the substitutions you would like to do, but you'd move the complexity to another place.

Instead of maintaining plain good old XML files, you would be creating something between XSLT and XML. Maybe you could just write XSLT (or XSL or XQUERY) and generate XML but I don't know anyone who is using it anymore. Last time I used it was when I was learning Computer Science a long time ago :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the `QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES` feature which will substitute `qmake` variables into the given input files and put the output in the build folder.

This runs at `qmake` time rather than at build time. If this is suitable then you just need to add a target to copy the generated files from the build dir to your source dir.

If you need it to run at build time then you can create a `.pri` file containing `QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES` and a target in the main .pro file that will run `qmake` on this file during the build process.

Main .pro file:

```
create_xml.commands += $(QMAKE) $$shell_quote($$PWD/config/generate_xml.pri) $$escape_expand(\n\t)
create_xml.commands += $(COPY) $$shell_quote($${OUT_PWD}/config.xml) $$shell_quote($$PWD/config) $$escape_expand(\n\t)
create_xml.commands += $(COPY) $$shell_quote($${OUT_PWD}/package.xml) $$shell_quote($$PWD/packages/my.app.id/meta) $$escape_expand(\n\t)
create_xml.depends = $$PWD/version.pri

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += create_xml
```

generate_xml.pri:

```
TEMPLATE = aux

message("Generating $$OUT_PWD/config.xml and $$OUT_PWD/package.xml")
# Get the version number
include(version.pri)
APP_VERSION = $$VERSION

QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES += package.xml.in config.xml.in
```

config.xml.in: Note that you need to escape the quotes.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<Installer>
  <Name>MyApp</Name>
  <Version>$$APP_VERSION</Version>
  ...
```